# How to construct geometrically $\sqrt[k]{n}$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k>2$

Tags: geometry, polynomials, roots, geometric-construction

As we know that square root of a number $n$ can be found by using a compass and a straight edge, given the line of length $n$.

What I want to know is how to find cube root, fourth root, fifth root or any $n$-th root of a number, by using any tools?

Few days ago I learned that origami (an art of folding paper) [can be used as a tool](http://www.ams.org/notices/200705/comm-casselman-web.pdf) to find cube root and even roots of a cubic equation. So I'm wondering about how to find any other $n$-th roots.

How to decide which kind of tools are necessary for the above mentioned operations? Thanks!

Comment: Fourtn root or any $2^n$th root can be found by repeatedly square-rooting given the number, atleast :)

Comment: I've edited your post to include a reference which gives details about how to solve cubic equations using origami.

Comment: Archimedes invented an incredibly simple tool for trisecting any angle between $0$ and $\pi$.  Trisections are related to cubic equations.

Answer (score 10):

Galois theory tells us that the only constructible roots are the $2^n$'th roots. These can be constructed by repeating the square root construction $n$ times. More precisely, if you start with the rational numbers, and allow only straightedge and compass operations on them, you generate the field of *[constructible numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number)*, which is characterized by the property of being the smallest field extension of the rationals which is closed under taking square roots. This implies that from a single line segment, the only constructible roots of its length are the $2^n$'th roots.

It is known the origami has enough structure to solve 3rd degree polynomial equations. Another system with the same expressive power can be found in the ancient greek/persian conic geometry. Indeed, roots of cubic polynomials can be found by intersections of conics. See e.g. [here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~dwh/papers/geomsolu/geomsolu.html).

It is known that *some* (but perhaps not all) quintic roots admit construction by compass and *marked ruler* operations, see [here](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/isrn/2012/487275/), and that all roots which are constructible in this system are of degree 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6.

The general problem of determining what operations one must allow to enable construction of $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is an open problem, it seems. And a hard one at that.

Comment: You can construct degree 4 roots with a marked ruler and compasses.  True, the theory in the referenced paper describes neusis constructive numbers as lying is a "2-3-5-6" tower over the rationale, but the radical solution for fourth-degree equations guarantees that these equations are also covered by the "2-3" part.

Answer (score 3):

Its seems that there are many [extended constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightedge_and_compass_construction#Extended_constructions) for the 3-th (cubic) root of two, for example this one based on J. H. Conway and R. K. Guy, The Book of Numbers, New York: Copernicus Books/Springer, 2006 pp. 194–195.:

Demonstration shows a construction of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ using a ruler with two marks
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ConstructingTheCubeRootOfTwo/

Using marked ruler is called neusis construction. It is more powerful than a conic drawing tool. But there are also negative results, and it is still open as to whether a regular 25-gon or 31-gon is constructible using this tool.